# from: command not found

Tags: python, pip, conda

I'm trying to make my own python pack using setuptools, setup.py file and installing it directly from github repository.
The package is sucessfully installed but when I call the command an error arises:

```
line 1: from: command not found.
```

somehow the binary file were not interpreted properly.

I'm using anaconda but have tried to install in other /bin diretories.

Comment: are you sure that you are typing this command in python, (not in bash or terminal).

Comment: l is to create command line tool too. This is the [github](https://github.com/computational-chemical-biology/ChemWalker) project link. The install instructions are on it. Sorry. I suppose that my question were not clear enough

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%22line+1%3A+from%3A+command+not+found%22

Comment: Add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) on the first line of the script: `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Answer (score 0):

you need to start the python interpreter first in the command window, so just type `python` and then try your command.

Comment: It works. But the problem is that my advisor did installed It and It worked regardless the interpreter start. Gonna share the [github](https://github.com/computational-chemical-biology/ChemWalker) link just in case someone wants to test.